# Is there a way to avoid using full http path links with Python generated HTML?

Tags: html, python-3.x

I'm generating HTML with Python using print statements.
It works, but for links to buttons or CSS, I have to specify the full path (ex: http://example.com/picture.jpg) instead of just "../picture.jpg"

Is there a way to avoid having to use the full http path?

Comment: Absolutely! Look up [**absolute, relative, and root-relative paths**](https://web.archive.org/web/20170406143859/http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php?ref). Then simply make sure you use the right one based on your filepath. If you update your question to indicate your filepath, I'll be more than happy to tell you how you can avoid using a full URL :)

Comment: I'm able to access my server side content in python with a relative path, but when I print HTML with python, I have to use the full URL.  For example, I have to use print("<a href='www.abc.com/index.html'> link </a>") instead of print("<a href='../html/index.html'> link </a>").  Is there some way to use the relative path?